# Is there a way to create and use store with @ngrx/store away from angular app?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I need to share the same (one global store) between two angular apps in site page. Is there any way to create @ngrx/store manually before apps bootstrap and next pass it as parameter to each angular2 app?

Comment: Why do you need that ? An angular app has a main module. If you declare your store into that module, it'll be accessible from children modules.

Comment: Yes, I understand that best practice is to use one angular app on the page. But I have some additional preferences - I try to build such structure that allows me to use angular2 apps as separate widgets in existing page. I can't wrap the whole page in one app, I can just embed it in different places. And I need to find a way how to join these apps. I have already found one solution with shared service, but next I catch ngrx with redux solution and now I want to replace my sharedService with this new option.

Comment: Any way I like ngrx/store solution with select values as Observables and I think it can be used as standalone tool in other not angular2 projects

Comment: Sounds more that you need modules instead of apps. If you really want to stick with 2 apps, I have no idea, sry

Answer (score 3):

#### Web Storage / Local Storage

Maybe you can explore Web Storage : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Quote from the page:

> Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

There are numerous example in the web, here is one: http://www.unitydatasystems.com/blog/2015/12/09/angular-2-caching-webservice-results-in-local-storage/

#### @ngrx/store + localstorage

This package : https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Quote:

> Simple syncing between ngrx store and local storage.

Comment: How can I use it with **@ngrx/store**? I don't need shared storage, I need shared Redux storage and features provided by this lib.

Comment: @DmitryShnyrev Updated. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you want to keep separate apps, I believe you need some kind of shared storage, either it is the `localstorage`, or some other solution that sync using the server side function.